# Did Judas realize his sin at the moment of the kiss?

Tags: greek, matthew, jesus, mark, judas

In my studies of the Gospel of Mark, I’ve stumbled upon an interesting differentiation in the words used for “kiss” as found in Mark 14:44-45.  The sign that Judas was to use to allow the captors to identify Jesus was a kiss, φιλήσω, *phileso* from *phileo* - a sign of affection.

However, the next verse reveals that Judas, after saying “Rabbi!” does not give Jesus a *phileo* kiss.  The prefix *kata*- is attached, an intensifier changing the meaning to a “fervent kiss”.  Only 3 other times do we see this kind of kiss:

- Mary kissing the feet of Jesus (Luke 7:38,45);
- the father of the prodigal son upon the son’s return (Luke 15:20);
- the emotional parting of Paul from the Ephesus brethren before he left Miletus (Acts 20:37).

Clearly something changed in Judas from originally intending to give Jesus a *phileo* kiss, but instead giving Jesus a *kataphileo* kiss.  Matthew records the same distinction (Matt 26:49).  Can we safely assume that it was here, in this moment that Judas broke? Is this definitive enough to assume this moment was where he suddenly realized the sin of his actions?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Comment: That is a stretch at best and an interpolation at worst.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** The text does not offer detailed information regarding Judas's personal thoughts or emotional state at that specific moment. Thus, any suggestion that Judas might have had a moment of realization or conviction is speculative and cannot be considered a conclusive fact.

**Now let's look a bit deeper:**

You note that the change in the nature of the kiss delivered by Judas, transitioning from a basic affectionate gesture to a more intense one, is marked by the employment of the intensifier "kata-" in the Greek language.

The best we could *infer* is that this shift *may* indicate a variation in Judas's psychological or emotional condition at that time. (The text does not explicitly confirm whether Judas was fully aware of the gravity of his actions at that moment)

Now let's turn to scripture:

> Matthew 27:1-5 NKJV
>
> When morning came, all the chief priests and elders of the people
> plotted against Jesus to put Him to death. 2 And when they had bound
> Him, they led Him away and delivered Him to Pontius Pilate the
> governor.
>
> **3 Then Judas, His betrayer, seeing that He had
> been condemned, was remorseful and brought back the thirty pieces of
> silver to the chief priests and elders, 4 saying, “I have sinned by
> betraying innocent blood.”**
>
> And they said, “What is that to us? You see to it!”
>
> 5 Then he threw down the pieces of silver in the temple and departed,
> and went and hanged himself.

You'll notice that in verse 3, it is only after seeing Jesus condemned that is says Judas was remorseful. This suggestion that **Judas experienced remorse following Jesus's condemnation, indicates that his awareness of the seriousness of his actions may have been after the kiss rather than occurring at the time of the kiss.** Or perhaps it simply hit him the most after Jesus was condemned rather than at the time of the kiss.

**In conclusion**, all we can say is that the alteration in the nature of Judas's kiss *may* indicate a change in his emotional state. However, the text lacks concrete evidence to ascertain if Judas had a moment of realization or conviction at that precise moment. **According to the scriptural narrative, Judas's remorse manifested after he observed Jesus's condemnation.** The severity of his actions might have grown gradually rather than occurring instantaneously. Interpretations concerning Judas's mental state at the time of the kiss are conjectural.